# Proving a solution of a Bernoulli type equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that

\begin{equation}
y(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{3x}{2x + 3c}}
\end{equation}

is a solution of

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{y}{2x} = -\frac{y^3}{3x}
\end{equation}

All the math to resolve this differential equation is already done. The exercise simply asks to prove the solution.

I start by pointing out that it has the form

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + P(x)y = Q(x)y^3
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
P(x) = \dfrac{1}{2x}, \qquad Q(x) = -\frac{1}{3x}
\end{equation}

Rewriting y(x) as

\begin{equation}
y(x) = (3x)^{\frac{1}{2}} (2x + 3c)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}

Getting rid of that square root, I'll need it later on to simplify things

\begin{equation}
[y(x)]^2 = 3x(2x + 3c)^{-1}
\end{equation}

Calculating dy/dx

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{2}(3x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(3)(2x + 3c)^{-\frac{1}{2}} + \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)(2x + 3c)^{-\frac{3}{2}}(2)(3x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \frac{3}{2}(3x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2x + 3c)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - (3x)^{\frac{1}{2}}(2x + 3c)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \\
&= (3x)^{\frac{1}{2}}(2x + 3c)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \left[\dfrac{3}{2}(3x)^{-1} - (2x + 3c)^{-1}\right] \\
&= y \left[\dfrac{3}{2}(3x)^{-1} - (2x + 3c)^{-1}\right] \\
&= \dfrac{y}{2x} - y(2x + 3c)^{-1} \\
&= \dfrac{y}{2x} - y\left(\dfrac{y^2}{3x}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{y}{2x} - \dfrac{y^3}{3x}
\end{align}

Finally

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + P(x)y &= \dfrac{y}{2x} - \dfrac{y^3}{3x} + \dfrac{y}{2x} \\
&= \dfrac{y}{x} - \dfrac{y^3}{3x}
\end{align}

which obviously isn't the same as equation 2. I don't know where I screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

Your work seems fine and we obtain

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{y}{2x} - \dfrac{y^3}{3x}$$

which should be the correct differential equation.

I don't understand why you have added the term $P(x)y$ in the last step.

Comment: It's how I verified solutions to differential equations so far. Left side has to be equal to right side, so I expected a minus sign in one of those y / 2x.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get an easier calculation by going over the logarithmic derivative,
$$
\log(y(x))=\frac12(\log(3x)-\log(2x+3c))
\\~\\
\implies
\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac12\left(\frac1x-\frac2{2x+3c}\right)
=\frac1{2x}-\frac1{3x}y(x)^2
$$
The last step is obtained by doing the minimum to eliminate the constant $c$.

As you can see, this again confirms your result.

---

As to the original equation itself, it solves as
$$
(y^{-2})'=-2y^{-3}y'=\frac{y^{-2}}x+\frac2{3x}\\
\left(\frac{y^{-2}}x\right)'=\frac2{3x^2}\implies \frac{y^{-2}}x=-\frac2{3x}+c\\
y(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac3{3cx-2}}
$$
which is quite different from your solution formula.

Comment: I didn't want to post the whole thing because the author goes a long way changing variables so the differential equation becomes linear. Then he goes from there and finds the solution in my OP.

I found a 2nd exercise in which I'm having exactly the same problem. I might as well email the book author, I've been on this for 2 freaking days now.

Comment: From the equation you reconstructed, you can see that the difference is just a sign. In long convoluted calculations it is easy to miss a sign change, especially if multiple sign changes are to be balanced.

Answer (score 0):

@kira1985 you should not add the p(x).y on both side, here you have to find the answer .

But you are using the answer it self to solve the problem .As the answer is unknown to have to just find the value of the P(x) and Q(x).

which is

/ = /2 − (^3)/3

P(x) = - 1/(2x)

Q(x) = - 1/(3x)

Is the write answer for the given question, please check your question once more.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

See the P(x) in the differential equation? That's where it **is known** from.

Comment: if u have to consider the P(x) and Q(x) then you have to integrate the differential equation using the Bernoulli's equation form as shown in the mentioned link(you have given above) example  which in your  case is an answer . check  you will not get the question from the answer .